# Reject routes for IPv6Tunnel in Windows 10

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6, tunnel

I am currently using Hurricane Electric's IPv6-Tunnel for IPv6-connectivity from my office computer (IT staff approved!).

Now I realized that HE.net has a peering dispute with Cogent. So all IPv6-traffic supposedly going to Cogent's network is not getting routed (though addresses are resolved). This creates a rather inconvenient problem for my machine having to wait for the timeout of that route to fall back to IPv4 (where routing is fine and successful).

So I need a way to disable IPv6-routes to Cogent's network. I've found on [this](https://www.agwa.name/blog/post/working_around_the_he_cogent_ipv6_peering_dispute) site "the Linux-way"™:

```
#!/bin/sh

for prefix in 2001:0550::/32 2001:067c:12e8::/48 2001:0978::/32 2607:9700::/32 2607:f298:000a::/48 2607:f5d8::/32 2610:00f8:2f00::/48 2610:00f8:2fed::/48 2620:009a:8000::/48 2620:00fb::/48 2620:00fb::/56
do
    ip -6 route add unreachable $prefix 2>/dev/null
done

exit 0
```

But how do I do this on Windows 10 Prof?

Comment: Hmm, if HE does not have any route at all to those addresses, I'd have expected _their_ routers to return a "Destination unreachable"...

Comment: Well, Cogent refuses to peer with them. I think the problem is that the addresses on Cogent still have AAAA-records. Anyway, what those two are doing is not what I can change (and the dispute is going on for at least 8 years). All that I can do right now is to some disable the route in Windows (like it is possible in linux as shown above).

Comment: Should this maybe be moved to serverfault?

Comment: You missed my point entirely...

Comment: To be honest, I don't know if they should reject it or if it is a problem with the peering agreement not existing or if they just want to be ready the same second the peering agreement finally is concluded. I'm just a hobbyist on this.

Comment: I'm not an expert at this either, but this particular kind of "being ready" seems weird, as routes between peers aren't added by hand, they are transmitted via BGP. So I don't see any reason for HE to attempt to route stuff via Cogent if they don't peer right now... (Surely there are _indirect_ paths between HE and Cogent via some other ISPs? The internet doesn't require everyone to be a direct peer of everyone else.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so there seems to be no way to do this properly in Windows. As a workaround I had to configure outbound rules in the Windows firewall which drop connections to those subnets. Seems to do the job.